# How do I set more specific rules for sphinx query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search-engine, sphinx

I have a database with list of movies and tv series.
The search I built uses Sphinx.

I use SPH_MATCH_ANY mode, because I want that if a person search for "x-men 2" he will also find entries about "x-men 1" and "x-men 3".

My problem is, it also searches for entries with "2", for example "Cars 2", or "Supernatural season 2".

I want to tell it not to search entries that have no 'x-men" in them.
In MYSQL I would write it like this:

```
MATCH (mname) AGAINST ('x-men') AND mname like '%x-men%'
```

or something like that.

In Sphinx I tried this:

```
$s->Query(x-men 2 "x-men",'test1');
```

But It still searched for entries with the number "2" in them..

So how can I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem solved, a guy from Sphinx forum gave me this solution:

```
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$s->Query("(x-men | 2) x-men",test1);
$s->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_ANY);
```

=)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think like a computer... for us is quite obvious that the word "x-men" is more relevant than "2", but for a computer they are both equal.

You could always tell sphinx to index "x-men 1","x-men 2" and "x-men 3" to the same index, using the [wordforms](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-wordforms)

```
x-men 1 > xmen
x-men 2 > xmen
x-men 3 > xmen
```

so if someone searches for "x-men 2" he will see the results for the 3 movies.  Or you could tell sphinx not to index single numbers, or set the [min length for indexes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-min-word-len).

But then the users might complain that they wanted ONLY to see the info of "x-men 2" and not the other movies.

In my opinion, when configuring a search engine you don't have to *guess* what the user wants as a result, because different users will expect different results, but you should always give him the tools to refine his search. For example, one person would expect that `x-men 2` returns all x-men movies, another person would expect it to return info related only to x-men 2, and (why not?) someone will expect it to return all movies containing the words "x-men" and "2"... you can't make everybody happy =P

Good Luck

Comment: Um, actually what I want is that the most relevant result would be first "xmen 2", and other related would go after "xmen 1". I just don't want sphinx to use numbers in it's search, when the main word is absent "x-men". I don't think that your solution will help me keep results relevance? Or am I wrong?

Comment: since you're using  SPH_MATCH_ANY all words will be treated as equal and since "2" is repeted several times, it has more weight than "x-men". There's no easy way to tell sphinx "give less weigth to the numbers IF they are next to a word". If you use SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED, you could use the [strict order](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#extended-syntax). And the query would be `"x-men" << 2`